# Ideas to help learn Blender for beginner

Tags: modeling

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas or something I could do to learn more of blender since I'm still a beginner, so ideas that are simple but will help me learn more. If anyone could also send like link to good tutorials or what not that would help a lot or maybe someone could teach me, either way I need a bit of help figuring out what to do to learn blender, please and than you!

Comment: In my opinion, at the beginning, follow tutorials on youtube, you have many, like Grant Abbitt's. Also at one point, stop following tutorials and create your own 3D animations, solving your own issues will help to learn. And also always take notes (by thematic categories) because it's hard to remember everything.

Comment: I would recommend cg boost's apple tutorial and Andrew price's anvil tutorial for starters. Later you would have to find tutorials based on what you like. There are thousands of blender tutorials out there. Also just like moonboots said at a point you will have to stop following tutorials and make your own projects but it's gonna take some time. At first you should learn about the features of blender and make yourself at home with it's interface. Notes are important too.

Comment: thank you, that is helpful and will help than you

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest watching some of Andrew Price's tutorials on youtube ([BlenderGuru](https://www.youtube.com/user/AndrewPPrice)).
His tutorials are really beginner-friendly. You can also check daily the [BlenderNation](https://www.blendernation.com/) website. There are tons of useful content and beginner-friendly items.

Then try to mix 3D modeling with something you like (an object such as a pencil, a baseball bat, a cap ...) and try to model it, but do it step by step, and start with something easy (not a full 3D character to begin with for example)

Once you get more confident, you can go a step further and try something harder.
You can also get some useful tips on [BlenderSecret](https://www.blendersecrets.org/) website, but it will be for later, it's not really beginner-friendly.

And of course, the most important thing: read the [Blender doc](https://docs.blender.org/)!
One of the hardest steps in 3D is to understand what each "3D word" means, and what it does (especially for a non-English native speaker). And just by understanding them, you'll be able to make more efficient searches to help you debug situations later on

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you @B.Pader that is very helpful ill try my best to do this thank you again